# How to use custom menu in joomla

Tags: menu, joomla, highlight

I use Joomla for create my web site. Now i create simple main menu. But this menu is not module joomla. For each item menu I add link in my source code(I copy this link when i add new item for module menu and bind this item with material). But when I go to different link in my menu, i don't know how to highlight this item when transition between menu items. Maybe needed create this from php code?

for example:

```
<div class="menu">
<a href = "LINK COPY FROM MODULE MENU"><div class="active">Home</div></a>
<a href = "LINK COPY FROM MODULE MENU"><div class="not_active">Store</div></a>
</div>
```

LINK COPY FROM MODULE MENU - this copy link from my module menu item.
I want to transition to Store and after this highlight this tabs

Comment: my link which i want to add into my direct link for item menu has the following format: index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1, index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2

Comment: I think there is a bit of a translation breakdown, are you referring to menu item aliases which point to already existing menu items?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using either the joomla menu module or one of the many joomla menu extensions? Just about all of the good modules include active highlighting. What can you possibly need to do that hasn't been done by one of the prebuilt modules?

Comment: Sorry for my english. Yes. I just copy the link with the existing menu and assign this link to their menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best would be that you use a module for this purpose. Extended menu is a very good option.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/tree-menus/163

It's very customizable and better than editing each menu item by hand or creating your own menu module.

SwMenuMaker http://www.swmenupro.com/ is a useful admin component to manage your menus as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today. I didn't see it necessary to download a module for something that takes 5' to write.

You can't link modules items or component item within your site without publishing them to a menu. Without publishing them to a menu, they have no location anyway.

You need to publish a menu module -the bog standard Joomla one is sufficient. Here you can link your component items and module items.

To make it *then* look and feel the way you want you need to write your css (as you might have done for your custom html module) and apply this css to the menu module you are altering using the 'Module Class Suffix' and 'Menu Class Suffix' fields.

This means you need name your menu and add the class in your that you are altering before it in your CSS:

`div.**yourmenuname** {some: style;}`

Hence your 'Module Class Suffix' this might look like

Then you place **yourmenuname** in then 'module class suffix' field in your menu module within the back end of Joomla. Then remember to place your styling in the 'Menu Class Suffix'.